# SCM_RIGHTS send file descriptor with less permissions

Tags: c, sockets, unix, file-descriptor

Is there a way to use unix sockets to send a file descriptor to another process but with less permissions than it was opened with? I am interested in the following scenario:

1. P1: open file "x" with RW permissions and get the file descriptor fd
2. P1: send fd to process P2 with read only permissions
3. P2: read something from the file using fd
4. P1: write something to the file using fd

Comment: You can use capsicum on FreeBSD: <https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/capsicum/papers/2010usenix-security-capsicum-website.pdf>. Hopefully more devs will realize just how wonderful this API really is and port it to more UNIX systems.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to change an existing file descriptor's access mode, or send it to another process with a different access mode. The closest thing that you can do is to open `"/dev/fd/%d"` or `"/proc/self/fd/%d"` to get a new file descriptor pointing to the same file as the old one, which you can make read-only, and then send that one to P2.

Comment: It would be nice, but if I do `new_fd = open("/dev/fd/%d", O_RDONLY)` I can still write: `write(new_fd, buff, sizeof(buff))` and it won't fail. As far as I understand some systems behave like this, meaning they behave like `new_fd = dup(old_fd)`.

Comment: @AndreiPangratie Which systems behave like that?

Comment: I just followed a link found on google(https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99706&seqNum=15), and tested it myself on a macos machine, didn't do further research on the subject.